# python logging: replace values in dictconfig file using environment variables

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I am running a FastAPI app using uvicorn as server.
To use less code as possible and to use tools that my environment already provides, I am passing logging configuration to uvicorn using the shell parameter during the run, as following:

```
uvicorn --reload --log-config=logging_conf.yaml main:app
```

where logging_conf.yaml is just dictconfig file written in YAML format.

This approach is convenient, because in the app you can just get get the logger, without configuring it, as follow:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Now I want to dockerize the application and I would like to change the log level to some logger, just using the environment variables. something like

```
loggers:
  uvicorn.access:
    level: os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL")
    handlers:
      - access
    propagate: no
```

Considering that the file is handled as a dict object I would guess that something is possible.
Unfortunately, I am not finding a way to achieve that

Comment: If nothing else, you could run an `ENTRYPOINT` script in your container that generates `logging_conf.yaml` from a template and handles environment variable substitution.

Comment: @larsks, thanks, my backup plan is to use envsubst, but I was trying to have a better solution

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `level: os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL")` would mean that the settings would be evaluated with `eval`. That is practically always a bad idea.

If uvicorn does not offer environment variable substitution, I guess the only way forward is not to use the uvicorn command line, make own `main` function and configure logging by reading the YAML file to dict, going through the dict (recursively) and updating all the values with `os.path.expandvars`.

My guess is that using `envsubst` to the configuration file would result in a much more compact implementation.